# Difference between these two breakers

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I'm still learning about all these stuff and I can't find an answer to my question, probably because I'm not sure of the correct terminology, and that's why I'm trying to ask to all the experienced users.
What's the difference between these two "types" of breakers?
I noticed that my sister's house (which is like 6 years) have the white type and my parents house have the black ones.
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mainly made for different electrical panels and/or systems.  Each make of panel has certain breakers that will fit in it and listed/labeled for that panel.  The black one is made by square D for square D panels and looks like it is for a standard North American electrical system.  The white one might for a European electrical system.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Without model numbers it's really difficult to tell you what the difference is aside from Preetika chose white and Square D chose the black color. The shape is different because their engineering teams decided that the specific shape works best for their product and will fit in a compatible electric panel.

Comment: @crip659 So, it is just for a different type of panel and there is no other advantage or disadvantage... Thanks if you add it as answer, I can mark it, thanks

Comment: Top one appears to be a DIN-rail mount physical form.

Comment: Usually, but not always, yes sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly made for different electrical panels and/or systems.

Each make of panel has certain breakers that will fit in it and listed/labeled for that panel.

The black one is made by square D for square D panels and looks like it is for a standard North American electrical system. The white one might for a European electrical system.

I am not sure about the white Preetika breaker since it seems to use odd voltage(240/415) for North American electrical systems.

The electrical panels should have a label on them that states which breakers and makes can go in the panel.

Comment: 240/415V would be normal in Europe.  A 415V three phase supply would have 240V phase to neutral.

Answer (score 4):

### Hardwire everything vs built-in bus/bus clip

The upper breaker is a "loose breaker". It simply has wire terminals in and out. Both the incoming and outgoing power must be hard-wired.  In simple applications, they make a "bus comb" which fits into the input screws of an entire row of breakers. However these have limits to their possible current.

The lower breaker uses a bus clip (this one bolts down). That means the input side does not need to be wired at all.  The panel its mounted in has a distribution bus built into it, and the breaker picks up supply power simply by being mounted. This allows a very robust distribution bus, capable of carrying as much as 400 amps.

This technique plays well with North American style split-phase, since virtually all panels have multiple phases in them.  If they were hand-wired Euro style, that would be a frequent source of mistakes. But with the bus *built in* to the panel itself, a multi-phase breaker simply picks up the correct phases when mounted.

### Europe-style vs NEC-style mounting

The top breaker is a "DIN Rail" breaker.  It is intended for European style installations where the service panels (consumer units) provide a standard DIN Rail mounting, and breakers are interchangeable across brands.

The bottom breaker is designed for a proprietary panel with a custom bus design.  In the North American consumer market there are 6 major bus designs, all incompatible with each other, and you must use breakers appropriate for the panel type you have.  But the upsides are that most breakers simply "clip on", and phasing is accomplished in the bus design so the user never has to think about it. A 2-pole or 3-pole breaker can simply go anywhere*  and "automagically" pick up the correct phases.   That particular unit is Square D "QO", a popular line.

However if you look close, you see this is a "QOB" type breaker, which is "QO" but with a **bolt-on** bus. It uses the same bus design, but requires the breakers be bolted down. This provides vibration resistance (think: vehicle), and deters unauthorized employees from tampering with the panel, since the bolt is "hot".

### Voltage rating

They both have "slash" ratings, meaning they have two ratings: the rating *between poles* (when used multi-pole), and the rating from pole to ground.

Both of these breaker types can be "sandwiched" to make a multi-pole breaker.  Some DIN rail breakers can field-apply "common trip"; the North American style breakers cannot.

The DIN rail breaker is rated 240V phase-ground and 415V phase-phase.  (It is NOT rated for 415V phase-ground).

The QOB breaker is rated 120V phase-ground and 240V phase-phase.  This is a lower rating obviously, however...

### Rated for DC power... or not.

The QOB breaker is rated for DC power up to 48 volts, of any polarity.  QOBs can be had which are listed for 120 volts DC.

The DIN rail breaker is not rated for DC at all. And probably would [do this](https://youtu.be/Oaq2cvoPBRk?t=191)...

### Visible trip window

The QOB breaker has a visible trip window, which shows that the breaker was *tripped* rather than shut off.  The DIN rail breaker does not.

### Chinese crud vs UL-Listed first rate gear

The Square D "QO" line is excellent gear.  The generic DIN rail breaker is a Chinese knock-off. You can tell because of the blatant and obvious Photoshop job putting the fake label on the picture.

---

---

---

* Well, not a "wild-leg delta" panel.